# Arduino - SD text file remove row

Tags: c++, arduino, text-files, android-sdcard, sd-card

I build script to delete one row from SD from .txt file.

Script works well but if I use longer string TextToRemove (for example length is 9) script ignore the line and println empty line. Additionally following condition is always true.

```
if (buffer.substring(0, buffer.length() - 1) != TextToRemove)
```

Basically idea is to

1. Create a new file `*_tmp`
2. Read first line from original file
3. Compare if line is equal to TestToRemove
4. If text is not equal println to tmp file, if is equal igonore the line
5. Repeat steps 2-4.
6. Delete original file
7. Rename `tmp` file (`remove _tmp`)

---

```
boolean RemovePin(String TextToRemove, String FileName) {

    String buffer;
    String FileName_new = FileName + "_tmp";
    File myFile;
    File myFile_new;
    boolean Removed = false;

    char filename2[FileName.length() + 1];
    FileName.toCharArray(filename2, sizeof(filename2));

    myFile = SD.open(FileName);

    myFile_new = SD.open(FileName + "_tmp", FILE_WRITE);

    if (myFile_new) {
        if (myFile) {

            while (myFile.available()) {
                buffer = myFile.readStringUntil('\n');
                if (buffer.substring(0, buffer.length() - 1) != TextToRemove) {
                    myFile_new.println(buffer.substring(0, buffer.length() - 1));
                } else {
                    Removed = true;
                }
            }
            myFile.close();
            SD.remove(filename2);

        } else {
            Serial.print("error opening ");
            Serial.println(FileName);
        }

        myFile_new.rename(SD.vwd(), filename2);
        myFile_new.close();

    } else {
        Serial.println("error opening tmp file");
    }

    return Removed;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Print `TextToRemove` at the beginning, and see what it stores in the problematic cases.

Comment: I added more println and in TextToRemove is exactly what I need to remove.

Comment: Are you sure `TextToRemove` doesn't contain any whitespace characters, like new line?

Comment: I checked TextToRemove length and when I put 222222222 to `TextToRemove` length is 9

Comment: If i put more `serial.print` before while I cannot open `*_tmp` file. When I comment additional `serial.print` scripts can open file ...

Comment: I removed a lot of `serial.println` from code and now it works. Can this be related to memory?